# Can you disable rounding in Vaadin spreadsheets?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

In Vaadin 8 [when I shrink the column width the number gets rounded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgulK.png). This causes a problem when I try to copy multiple cell values, I actually copy the "rounded" value which is terrible for my use case.

If I could disable the rounding for numbers entirely, and have the cell behave just like it does when text overflows, that would resolve my problem. But I couldn't find any methods that do this, and my searches have been unsuccessful.